# Hexadecimal XOR with 2 values in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, hex, xor

I can't find the solution for very easy question.

Code in JavaScript:

```
var x = -1 ^ 0xF00F9344;
```

In this case x value is 267414715

Code in PHP:

```
$x = -1 ^ 0xF00F9344;
```

The result is -4027552581

Any idea, how to get 267414715 (correct) result in PHP?

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.ideone.com/DILsQ).

Comment: Yes, works here too. What version of PHP do you have? and on what hardware?

Comment: Works for me on a 32bit machine, but I get the same beaviour on a 64bit machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While javascript bit operations are always 32-bit, php depends on the platform's word size:

on a 32-bit platform

```
$n    = "11110000000011111001001101000100"
-1^$n = "00001111111100000110110010111011"  = 267414715
```

on a 64 bit platform

```
$n    = "0000000000000000000000000000000011110000000011111001001101000100"
-1^$n = "1111111111111111111111111111111100001111111100000110110010111011" = -4027552581
```